Spin-Orbit coupling eigenvectors
I am studying the spin-orbit coupling from Townsend's book on QM. When solving the eigenvalue problem:
\begin{equation}
    2  \hat{\textbf{L}} \cdot  \hat{\textbf{S}} \left|\lambda\right\rangle = \lambda \hbar^2 \left|\lambda\right\rangle
\end{equation}
on the basis
\begin{equation} \left| l, m, + \textbf{z} \right\rangle  , \ \   
 \left| l, m+1, - \textbf{z} \right\rangle 
\end{equation}
with solutions $\lambda = l$ and $\lambda = -(l+1)$. It says that replacing these into the eigenvalue equation we can find the linear combination of the given kets that are eigenstates of $\hat{\textbf{L}} \cdot  \hat{\textbf{S}}$.
The matrix representation for the operator is the following:
$ \begin{pmatrix}
m & \sqrt{l(l+1)- m(m+1)} \\
\sqrt{l(l+1)- m(m+1)} & -(m+1)) 
\end{pmatrix}  $
I have been trying to do this and get to the equations $11.107a$ and $11.107b$:
$$   \left| j=l+\frac{1}{2}, m_j \right\rangle   = \sqrt{\frac{l+m+1}{2l+1}} \left| l, m, + \textbf{z} \right\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{l-m}{2l+1}}\left| l, m+1, - \textbf{z} \right\rangle
$$
$$
  \left| j=l-\frac{1}{2}, m_j \right\rangle   = \sqrt{\frac{l-m}{2l+1}} \left| l, m, + \textbf{z} \right\rangle - \sqrt{\frac{l+m+1}{2l+1}} \left| l, m+1, - \textbf{z} \right\rangle
$$
When I try replacing the eigenvalues in the first equation to find the eigenvectors, I end up with (for $ \lambda = l$):
$$ c_1(l-m) = \sqrt{l(l+1)- m(m+1)} c_2 $$
$$ \sqrt{l(l+1)- m(m+1)}c_1 = c_2(l+m+1) $$
Which leads me to a different answer (same thing for the other eigenvalue) . Am I doing the right procedure to get to that linear combination of the basis kets? Maybe I am  confused on how these coefficients (the entries of a column vector) represent the kets. I appreciate the help.

To obtain the eigenvalues of $LS$ the simplest way is to compute the square $(L+S)^2$. Of every square term you get the eigenvalues easily, hence you get eigenvalues of the double product.

Consider the first equation
$$_1(−)=\sqrt{(+1)−(+1)}_2$$
A solution is $c_1=\sqrt{(+1)−(+1)}$ and $c_2=l-m$. However, the associated quantum state is not normalized since
$$\eqalign{
   c_1^2+c_2^2&=(+1)−(+1)+(l-m)^2\cr
   &=(2l+1)(l-m)\cr
   }$$
Dividing $c_1$ and $c_2$ by $\sqrt{(2l+1)(l-m)}$, we get the expected solution
$$c_1=\sqrt{l+m+1\over 2l+1},\quad\quad
   c_2=\sqrt{l-m\over 2l+1}$$
since $l(l+1)-m(m+1)=(l+m+1)(l-m)$.
